# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un like con dynamic linq?

Tags: c#, linq

En SQL Server tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
select top 1000 * 
from Empleados.dbo.Usuario (nolock) where nombre_usuario like 'sa%'
```

Ahora quisiera hace lo mismo pero con Dynamic Linq, hice algo similar pero solo utilice contains:

```
var c = from x in Table.AsEnumerable() where x.Field<string>(Columna).Contains(Valor.ToUpper()) select x;
```

Pero si nos damos cuenta lo que yo quiero en realidad es obtener los registros que comiencen con la cadena dada.

Espero me haya dado a entender.

Answer (score 3):

Gracias por leer mi pregunta, afortunadamente he encontrado la solución, la dejaré por si alguien tiene la misma duda.

```
 var start = from x in Table.AsEnumerable() where x.Field<string>(Columna).StartsWith(Valor.ToUpper()) select x;
```

Saludos.

Comment: Deberias de aceptar tu respuesta.

Comment: @Einer para aceptar su respuesta deben pasar 48 horas.